# Want to put time gap between two events in Android application

Tags: android, multithreading, animation, delay

I want put delay between two flips of the same image on ImageView.
i.e.
(1). Image loads with Animation
(2). Wait for 1 or 1.5 seconds
(3). Image changes with animation on the same ImageView.

I tried to set Thread.Sleep() , didn't work.

And yes, these all things I want to be done on android.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at TimerTask. So, you set the time interval before it invokes the event of animation.

```
timer = new Timer() ;
task = new TimerTask() {
@Override
public void run() {
   // some code here..
    }
};
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 5000, 1000 ) ;
```

Hope this sample helps you..

Comment: I just want to change image to new one, and after some time original image should be loaded on the same imagebutton. with animation .